# How to convert a raster from Integer format to Float

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator

I have a classification image in integer format but need it in a float for weightings before running a least cost path analysis.

I have tried the raster calculator:

float("raster_1")

But this did not complete the conversion.

How should I complete this task?

Comment: How does it not complete the conversion?  It throws an error, it converts some, but not all of the raster, etc.?  If it does throw an error, what is it?  Also, what format is your raster?  And where is it stored?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using raster calculator I assume you have a spatial analyst license available. You can use the `float()` tool in your spatial analyst toolbox (look under `Math`). The tool does exactly what you want.

[image: float-tool]